# Private message to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to make a bot be able to send a private message to a specific person? (using user ID)

> no, `message.author` is not what I need!

I'm using `discord.js` and `node.js`

Answer (score 1):

```js
client.users.fetch('123456789').then((user) => {
    user.send("My Message");
});
```

Dont forget replace `"123456789"` with the user id :D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this code is inside of an `async` function

```
// Getting the user object
const user = await <Client>.users.fetch('userID');

if (user) user.send('message').catch(error => {
    // code if error occurs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [User.send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send)() method.

> Here's an example of how it can be done by fetching the user
>
> *Make sure this is an async function, or the `await` will return an error.*

```js
const user = await <client>.users.fetch("USER ID"); // Replace <client> with your client variable (usually client or bot)

user.send("Message to send");
```